# Update DataTable using php from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the example ->  http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

In my situation Im sending an ajax call to a php script that gathers an array of parameters. I am then taking these parameters and trying to dynamically (and visibly) insert a new row in the DataTable

at the line: `t.row.add( [` I'm getting an error: "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"

Can anyone help?

```
<script>

    var asInitVals = new Array();
var oTable = $('.datatable-add-row table').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
    "aaSorting":[[0,'desc']],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "<span>Filter all:</span> _INPUT_",
        "sLengthMenu": "<span>Show entries:</span> _MENU_",
        "oPaginate": { "sFirst": "First", "sLast": "Last", "sNext": ">", "sPrevious": "<" }
    }
     });

     $(".dataTables_wrapper tfoot input").keyup( function () {
          oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $(".dataTables_wrapper tfoot input").index(this) );
      });

     (function newjobs() {
     var t = $('.datatable-add-row table').dataTable();
         var inputjob = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
            url: "create_new_job.php",
    cache:false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#invisible_button').on( 'click', function () {
            t.row.add( [
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[6],
            data[7],
            data[8]             
            ] ).draw();
        } );
        $('#invisible_button').click();
    }
});

    inputjob.done(function(data) {      
        setTimeout(newjobs, 10000);    
});

    inputjob.fail(function(data) { 
        alert('Job not added....'); 
    });
   })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging this we look at the fact that it is telling you 'add' is not a property of 'undefined'.  This means that 'row' is an undefined member of t.  This tells us that t is something [or it would have started by saying 'row' is not a property of undefined].

So this tells me that t is something, just not the datatable object you expect it to be.

Looking at the example link you including on your post, I see ".DataTable()" being used.  Objects and properties in JavaScript are case sensitive so ".dataTable()" is not the same as ".DataTable()".

Change the case and see if this fixes your problem.